# Dagger generating multiple instances of retrofit interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, rx-java2

I am new to Dagger and Retrofit. I am having issue where multiple instances of retrofit custom interceptor are being generated despite declared singleton in dagger module. I only require one instance.

**Dagger Module**

```
@Module
public class ApiModule
{
    private Config config;

    public ApiModule(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClient()
    {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public AuthenticationRequestInterceptor provideRequestInterceptor()
    {
        return new AuthenticationRequestInterceptor();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance()
    {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        // add session headers interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(provideRequestInterceptor());

        // add logging as last interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getConfig().getBaseUrl())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build()) //for logging purpose remove later
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Retrofit Interceptor**

```
public class AuthenticationRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor
{
    private Map<String, String> defaultHeaders;

    public AuthenticationRequestInterceptor()
    {
        this.defaultHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setDefaultHeaders(Map<String, String> headers)
    {
        this.defaultHeaders = headers;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
    {
        Request request = chain.request();

        Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();

        for (String key: this.defaultHeaders.keySet())
        {
            requestBuilder.addHeader(key, this.defaultHeaders.get(key));
        }

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Connector**

```
public class Connect
{
    @Inject Retrofit retrofit;
    @Inject Config config;
    @Inject AuthenticationRequestInterceptor headerInterceptor;

    public Connect(PercentApp application)
    {
        ((PercentApp) application).getComponent().inject(this);
```

> /** Setting interceptor headers here, but this get sets in a different
>   instances than the one gets called later in postUser **/

```
     headerInterceptor.setDefaultHeaders(generateDefaultAuthHeaders());
    }

    public void postUser(Observer observer, User user)
    {
        if(retrofit != null)
        {
            ApiServices api = retrofit.create(ApiServices.class);
            Observable<HashMap> observable = api.postUser("{post something}");
            observable.
                    subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(observer);
        }
    }

}
```

And in my Application I create instance of Dagger like this:

```
DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .apiModule(new ApiModule(new Config(environment)))
                .build();
```

> And in my MainActivity I create instance of Connect

```
Connect connect = new Connect((MyApp) getApplication());
User user = new User();
connect.postUser(new UserObserver(this), user);
```

***Now the problem is that AuthenticationRequestInterceptor contructor gets called twice which I don't understand why and because of that the headers that I set get sets to a different instance of Interceptor. Please help. Thanks***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `provideRequestInterceptor` directly

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(AuthenticationRequestInterceptor authInterceptor)
{
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    // set your desired log level
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    // add session headers interceptor
    httpClient.addInterceptor(authInterceptor);

    // add logging as last interceptor
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getConfig().getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build()) //for logging purpose remove later
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why is that as I declared requestInterceptor as @singleton in dagger , why its creating multiple instances of it. Can we not call one provider inside another in the same module.

Comment: Dagger2 doesn't work as Spring (in Spring when you call the method it proxies it so you're not calling *directly* to the real method). Just let Dagger2 do its thing. If you need an object declare it in the arguments of the method

Comment: @user606669 if you want value from one provider inside another, then you should put this value to parameters list (compare my code with your). for Singletone annotation Dagger checks method calling in generated code, it can not check your code, because it uses compile-time injection, not runtime.

Comment: Thanks, if I follow above practice how do I pass params then to this method when I inject it.

provideRetrofitInstance(AuthenticationRequestInterceptor authInterceptor)

Lets say I inject it in MainActivity like this:

"@Inject Retrofit retrofit;"

now what how to pass the AuthenticationRequestInterceptor. Sorry if its silly question as im new to this.

Comment: By injecting `retrofit` that instance will already have the interceptor. If you also want the interceptor instance you will have to inject the same way you inject `retrofit`

Comment: @user606669 You may see how Dagger do injection in generated class ApiModule_ProvideRetrofitInstanceFactory (see in `build/generated/source/apt/debug` )

Comment: Thanks to both. I'll try these changes now, and update here.

Comment: Awesome thats quite good piece of information. Now I know a little bit more about dagger than I used to know before. Thanks guys. Problem not fully solved but thats another issue :)

Answer (score 1):

There is on point creating another of instance OkHttpClient.Builder within the provideRetrofitInstance method, you have already provided it in your ApiModule. Be nice and use as httpClient argument instead.

```
@Module
public class ApiModule
{
   private Config config;

   public ApiModule(Config config) {
      this.config = config;
   }

   @Provides @Singleton
   public OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClient()
   {
      return new OkHttpClient.Builder();
   }

   @Provides @Singleton
   public AuthenticationRequestInterceptor provideRequestInterceptor()
   {
      return new AuthenticationRequestInterceptor();
   }

   @Provides @Singleton
   public Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient, 
        AuthenticationRequestInterceptor authInterceptor)
   {
       HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       // set your desired log level
       logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        //YOU DON'T THIS LINE, REFER TO ARGUMENT LIST
       //OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


      // add session headers interceptor
      httpClient.addInterceptor(authInterceptor);

      // add logging as last interceptor
      httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  

      return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getConfig().getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build()) //for logging purpose remove later
            .build();
    }
}
```