# Add headers to request using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, session-cookies, interceptor, okhttp

I'm trying to send requests with authentication headers, but it seems that the server cannot identify the client. 
I used [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) tutorial, and implemented an interceptor as follows:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String authId;
private String authToken;

public AuthenticationInterceptor(String authId, String authToken) {
    this.authId = authId;
    this.authToken = authToken;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();

    if (authId != null && authToken != null) {
        Timber.d("adding auth headers for: " + this);
        builder.header("auth_id", authId)
                .header("auth_token", authToken);
    }

    Request request = builder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to send authenticated requests to the server, it returns error response 409. The server guy told me that I'm missing those params: (which received by Postman for instance)

```
    “accept”: [
        “*/*”
    ],
    “accept-encoding”: [
        “gzip, deflate”
    ],
    “cookie”: [
        “PHPSESSID=ah1i1856bkdln5pgmsgjsjtar3"
    ]
```

- I thought using Dagger2 might cause this issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868976/4449366)), so I've isolated the okHttpClient, but it still doesn't work.
- Here is my usage implementation (very straightforward):

  ```
  Retrofit retrofit;
  OkHttpClient client;
  AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor;
  HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;

  private void testHeaders() {
  loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
      @Override
      public void log(String message) {
          Timber.i(message);
      }
  });
  loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

  client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
          .build();

  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
          .client(client)
          .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS)
          .build();

  retrofit.create(EntrOnline.class).getLoginToken("email@email.com", "XXX").enqueue(new Callback<NewAccount>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<NewAccount> call, Response<NewAccount> response) {

          authenticationInterceptor = new AuthenticationInterceptor(response.body().getAuthId(), response.body().getAuthToken());

          client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                  .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                  .addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor)
                  .build();

          retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                  .client(client)
                  .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS)
                  .build();

          retrofit.create(EntrOnline.class).getKeys("50022d8a-b309-11e7-a902-0ac451eb0490").enqueue(new Callback<List<NewEkey>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<NewEkey>> call, Response<List<NewEkey>> response) {
                  Timber.d("Test Api");
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<NewEkey>> call, Throwable t) {

              }
          });

      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<NewAccount> call, Throwable t) {

      }
  });
  ```

  }

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("sendWalletMoney")
Call<WalletResponse> sendWalletMoney(@Field("sender") String sender,
                                     @Field("receiver") String receiver,
                                     @Field("amount") String amount,
                                     @Field("trnsx_type") String trnsx_type,
                                     @Field("currency") String currency,
                                     @Field("module_name") String module_name);
```

Comment: I've added this custom header - didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [server issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409).
You can try adding the headers he talked about in your interceptor.

```
builder.addHeader("Accept", "*/*").addHeader("accept-encoding",  "gzip, deflate")
```

But the cookie should be used on the web to keep track of the current session. Shouldn't be needed on the API.